# Batch prediction returns same predictions for all instances in the same batch (Google AI platform object detection model)

Tags: tensorflow, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-ml, object-detection-api

I've successfully trained an object-detection algorithm largely following this [tutorial](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/training/docs/algorithms/object-detection). I am able to submit a batch prediction job (as outlined [here](https://cloud.google.com/ai-platform/prediction/docs/batch-predict#submitting_a_batch_prediction_job)), using the following `prediction_instances.json` file:

```
{"encoded_image": {"b64": "3wrJITSQiN..."}, "key": "1"}
{"encoded_image": {"b64": "lFd/dhbajX..."}, "key": "2"}
{"encoded_image": {"b64": "yrThwP50t8..."}, "key": "3"}
{"encoded_image": {"b64": "P+Qmx+TD92..."}, "key": "4"}
{"encoded_image": {"b64": "5yd5UiOokG..."}, "key": "5"}
...
```

of length 100, where every line contains a b64-encoded image.

The batch-prediction job runs without errors and the three files `prediction.results-00000-of-00003`, `prediction.results-00001-of-00003`, and `prediction.results-00002-of-00003` (containing 21, 39, and 40 instances, respectively) are saved in my bucket. So far so good.

The problem is the following: **The predicted bounding boxes (and corresponding labels) are the same for all prediction instances within one file.** For example, this is the shortened (I've only included 3 bounding boxes per image and only 3 images) `prediction.results-00000-of-00003` file.

```
{
"detection_classes": [27.0, 3.0, 5.0, …], 
"detection_boxes": [[0.29, 0.31, 0.34, 0.38],  [0.39, 0.39, 0.44, 0.46],  [0.43, 0.39, 0.49, 0.47],  …],
"detection_scores": [0.589, 0.500 0.480, …], 
"key": “1”, 
"num_detections": 44.0
}
{
"detection_classes": [27.0, 3.0, 5.0, …], 
"detection_boxes": [[0.29, 0.31, 0.34, 0.38],  [0.39, 0.39, 0.44, 0.46],  [0.43, 0.39, 0.49, 0.47],  …],
"detection_scores": [0.589, 0.500 0.480, …], 
"key": “2”, 
"num_detections": 44.0
}
{
"detection_classes": [27.0, 3.0, 5.0, …], 
"detection_boxes": [[0.29, 0.31, 0.34, 0.38],  [0.39, 0.39, 0.44, 0.46],  [0.43, 0.39, 0.49, 0.47],  …],
"detection_scores": [0.589, 0.500 0.480, …], 
"key": “3”, 
"num_detections": 44.0
}
...
```

You can see that all the data is exactly the same except for the "key"-variables, which are different.

In the other two files, the same happens; however, with different data. That is, it seems like for the 100 images that I send as input, I get only 3 predictions as output (one for each output file).

When I submit just one image with the following one-lined `.json`:

```
{"encoded_image": {"b64": "3wrJITSQiN..."}, "key": "1"}
```

everything works fine (that is, it predicts perfect bounding boxes for that image).

Comment: I am encountering similar issue, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73597183/batch-prediction-return-same-output-for-all-input-in-the-same-batch  
Did you find the reason?